# Display the message in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

An RMI Program is running on a remote machine(RMI Server), We invoked this program through the Web app(RMI client). When the RMI client invokes the RMI Server, the server instantiate a program and the result is send back to client through the simple network client code. The sample code as below.

### **RMI server code**

```
try {
            if(monitor == null) return;
            monitor.stop();
            SimpleClient sc=new SimpleClient(client,1131,"`file Monitor stopped");
            //System.out.println("---aaaaa---");
            sc.sendMsg();
            System.out.println("Monitor stopped");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

### RMI Client code

```
public static List plusOne003Test(String ipAddress, boolean isstopped) {
    ArrayList alist = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("All Plus one....plusOne003Test");
        Class testClass = Class.forName("PlusOneClient11");
        System.out.println("class Name::::::>"+testClass.getName());

        Method testMethod = testClass.getMethod("plusOne003Test",
                new Class[] { String.class,boolean.class});
        alist = (ArrayList) testMethod.invoke(testClass.newInstance(),ipAddress,isstopped);
        //System.out.println("ALIST::::::>"+alist);
        System.out.println("before create server");
        SimpleServer t=new SimpleServer(1131);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("after create server");
        System.out.println("test3:::>" + alist.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return alist;
}
```

### **network code for received the message from the RMI Server**

```
 public class SimpleServer extends Thread{
          private ServerSocket serverSocket;
          public SimpleServer(int port) throws IOException   {

   try{
       ServerSocketFactory ssf=ServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
       serverSocket=ssf.createServerSocket(port);
      }catch(BindException be){
       be.printStackTrace();
   }
}
public void run(){
  while(true)
  {
     try
     {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        /*System.out.println("Just connected to "
              + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());*/
        DataInputStream in =
              new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        String rec=in.readUTF();
        System.out.println("\n"+rec+"\n");
        if(rec.contains("`")){
            String rec1[]=rec.split("`");
            **JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rec1[0]+"\n"+rec1[1]);**
            ----------------------------------------------------------------
        System.out.println("\n"+rec+"\n");

        }


     }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
     {
         s.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");

        break;
     }catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
     }
  }
}
}
```

The code JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rec1[0]+"\n"+rec1[1]); message needs to be displayed in the web app alert message.

Comment: I don't see anything recognizable as RMI here, or any way in which RMI relates to whatever your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between server side (JSP, Servlet) and client side (HTML, Javascript) code in this case. JSP is used to generate the HTML code, i.e. it runs on the server, generates the HTML that is sent to browser, and *then stops*. So it is not possible to put any messaging client's code into the JSP.

Basically, the web technology is a request-response technology, the communication is initiated by the client. But there are of course ways to implement also a server-initiated communication. I would recommend you to have a look at HTML5 WebSockets (e.g. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html), which should be the most standard way to implement such functionality.

Comment: Hi Jozef, thanks for the quick reply. I wants to show the pop-up message instead of the java alert message. For that only i need some help. We have to use jsp as a front end.

Comment: JSP generates the HTML page. The browser displays it. You need to make  the browser to connect to your RMI server and then react to the messages coming from the server. The WebSockets are the way (one of many, but probably the best) to do it.